# Xcode project send from freelancer, won't run, says ''build failed''

Tags: xcode

I just received my iphone app in a xcode file from my freelancer. 
When i open the project in xcode and clicks ''run'' it says ''build failed'' and i get the following message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIDA0.jpg

How do i fix this? I am new to xcode and need a detailed description of how to do it.

Comment: You are really asking in the wrong place, aren't you? It would be the freelancer that sent you the app that needs asking. It's quite easy to make a mistake so that an app will only build and run on the original developer's hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read in the screenshots, the reason for this error that your freelancer did not "clean up" the project properly before sending it to you. You can fix this, but that depends on your experience in working with Xcode. Please contact him/her because it is easy to fix it there.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project in Xcode, go to Product -> Clean, press option key to show "Clean Build Folder..." and select this option.

Now rebuild your project.